# Is there an O(1) operation to find the Nth digit of Pi?

Tags: algorithms, pi

I'm afraid that 10 minutes of googling isn't finding references to a paper that I thought existed. I remember seeing some years ago a reference to a paper that claims to have proven an algorithm that can return a single Nth digit of Pi in constant time (O(1)).

Does anyone know the reference I'm thinking of? Was it disproven or a hoax?

Comment: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/20010.5.shtml This gives the $N$th digit using $O(N)$ time and $O(\log N)$ storage. The term to google search is "spigot algorithm", which refers to algorithms that generate digits with limited intermediate storage.

Comment: @Ian That algorithm gives the $n$th base 16 digit. Usually, unless specified, $n$th digit means base 10.

Comment: I'd be thrilled with any base that can do O(1) computation. I'm starting to think I made up the constant time, and that the best we know currently are O(N)

Comment: As I point out in my answer, $O(1)$ is not possible. I don't know the complexity of the base 16 method, but my understanding is that the main advantage of the base 16 method is that it is parallelizable, not that it is better than $O(N)$.

Answer (score 4):

Any $O(1)$ algorithm would have to use only $N$ digits of the input $n$, for some $N$, and that would mean the output would repeat. So there is no algorithm that is $O(1)$ to compute then $n$th digit of any irrational number.

There is no known good algorithm for finding the $n$th base $10$ digit of $\pi$ without effectively computing the prior digits. [There is such an algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula) for base $16$. I'm not sure what the algorithm's efficiency is.

Comment: Can O(1) algorithm exist, if it reads N sequntially until termination symbol? It can gain information from N.

Comment: On other words, can algorithm O(log(N)) exist, where log(N) is for reading N only?